# Restricting shortcode for users

Tags: shortcode, capabilities

anyway to block any user /role(except the admin) to use shortcode? i want to keep some specific shortcode secret. if somehow users come to know, they cant use it. if only admin writes the shortcode it will make changes to site, but if someone else write the shortcode it will be taken as a simple text.

Comment: I think you need to check the rendered post author, and if the author is not an admin, prevent those shortcodes from being rendered.

Comment: thaMks brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this might work with you

```
function myshortcode(){

$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //Run shortcode
}

}

add_shortcode('myshortcode','myshortcode');
```

Comment: That depends on the user who's viewing the content though, not the user who added the shortcode to the page?

Comment: it's limit shortcode usage based on user role

Comment: Bruh, take my heart.